# Repeating a block matrix many times in diagonal part of a block matrix, with the off-diagonal blocks all zero matrices?

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create a block diagonal matrix with the diagonal blocks being repeated a certain number of times, with the off-diagonal blocks being all zero matrices. For example, suppose we start with a matrix with the following:

```
> diag.matrix

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5
  [2,]  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.5
  [3,]  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5
  [4,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.5
  [5,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  1.0
```

I would like this matrix to be the diagonal block matrix so that in the end I have something like:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [2,]  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [3,]  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.5   0.5
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5   0.5
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.5   0.5
 [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  1.0   0.5
[10,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5   1.0
```

Here, we have the same block matrix above repeated twice in the block diagonals. If I wanted to do this efficiently an arbitrary number of times, is there a way to do it? thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1) kronecker** If `M` is your matrix and `k` is the number of times you want it repeated then:

```
kronecker(diag(k), M)
```

For example,

```
M <- matrix(0.5, 5, 5) + diag(0.5, 5)
k <- 2
kronecker(diag(k), M)
```

giving:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [2,]  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [3,]  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.5  0.5  0.5   0.5
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.5  0.5   0.5
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.5   0.5
 [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  1.0   0.5
[10,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5   1.0
```

**1a) %x%** The last line of code can alternately be written as:

```
diag(k) %x% M
```

**2) Matrix::bdiag** Another possibility if you want to save space is to create a sparse matrix of class `"dgMCatrix"`.  It does not store the zero values.  See `?bdiag` :

```
library(Matrix)

bdiag(replicate(k, M, simplify = FALSE))
```

giving:

```
10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,] 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 .   .   .   .   .  
 [2,] 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.5 .   .   .   .   .  
 [3,] 0.5 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.5 .   .   .   .   .  
 [4,] 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0 0.5 .   .   .   .   .  
 [5,] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0 .   .   .   .   .  
 [6,] .   .   .   .   .   1.0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
 [7,] .   .   .   .   .   0.5 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.5
 [8,] .   .   .   .   .   0.5 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.5
 [9,] .   .   .   .   .   0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0 0.5
[10,] .   .   .   .   .   0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0
```

**2b) Diagonal** or to create a sparse matrix of class `"dgTMatrix"` :

```
Diagonal(k) %x% M
```

Comment: Can this be done with matrix multiplication instead of kron? 
Have some A, B st. A*r*B = kron(eye(2), r) ?